# Generation of AES Key in angular application

Tags: angular, encryption

How can i generate a AES session key which is secure in an angular application , the goal is to secure the payload of the user

Comment: use https between web app and backend and it will be encrypted automatically in flight

Comment: yes , it is already being encrypted but another layer of encryption is needed to secure the payload as the user is able to view passwords or such during login/signup

Comment: passwords are user supplied.  What exactly would it mean to encrypt it?

Comment: Agreed user provides the password but those are visible in network panel. There by securing it would be ideal , even google does it in our requests

Comment: and where do you plain to put the AES key that the user can't get into the DOM console and pull it out?

Comment: In localStorage using secureLS

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your AES key by using random bits as follows

```html
  generateSessionKey(keyLengthInBytes) {
    const keyBuffer = new Uint8Array(keyLengthInBytes);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(keyBuffer);
    return Array.from(keyBuffer)
      .map((byte) => byte.toString().padStart(2, "0"))
      .join("");
  }
```

For more security you can add a timestamp to verify the authenticity of the aes key shared.